USDT Tokens to transfer with Sponsor Wallet to cover gas fee
We have a use case where we need to move USDT tokens from a temporary wallet to a main wallet. For this, the gas fee needs to be sponsored, as the temporary wallet does not have the native token to cover the gas fees. Unfortunately, we couldn't find clear documentation regarding USDT tokens for this specific use case.
How to Implement this user case

Consider as workaround to transfer the native token to the temporary wallet, there will be tokens to cover the gas fees, unfortunately some "dust" may rest in the wallet after the transaction.
It is possible to transfer a higher amount of token to the temporary wallet, and after remove all tokens, but there will be more than one tansactions and also fees.

there are many options for this, think you are new to smart contracts and blockchain. I already resolved this by gas sponsorship. It would help if you educated yourself on the latest blockchain developments.
https://www.erc4337.io/

If you solved your own question, answer it, may be useful for other people with the same question.

I did it using the gsn relay server method.
https://docs.opengsn.org/
It worked like a charm. Very easy can use it for any EOA Wallets and works on any ERC 20 or ERC 721 tokens,
If the wallet ERC 4337 User Abstraction wallet it has more control.
